# How to dump an entire structure in a textfile using winapi

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, file-io

Is it Possible to dump an entire structure into a file using CreateFile/Writefile(WINAPI)

I dont want to use fstream objects.So please dont suggest answers with them.
Thanks in advance

```
Struct abc
{
    int a;
    int b;
    char c;
}
```

i want to do it using WriteFile/CreateFile API.Currently i am doing like this

```
struct abc
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
};

void main()
{   
    struct abc ob;
    ob.a=1;
    ob.b=2;
    ob.c=3;
    DWORD dwNumBytesWritten = 0;
    HANDLE hFile;
    hFile = CreateFile(FILENAME,
        FILE_APPEND_DATA, 
        FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
        NULL,
        OPEN_ALWAYS,
        FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
        NULL);

    WriteFile(hFile,
              (LPCVOID)&ob,
              sizeof(abc),
              (LPDWORD)&dwNumBytesWritten,
              NULL);
}
```

But the output is some unknown symbols.

Comment: As text or as binary, what kind of structure? More details please.

Comment: It is possible but why do you want to do it? It would be good to know first as to what the structure is and how you would later interpret the contents.

Comment: @arzon i am making a logger.So if i need to dump all the values that are in a struct and if it is possible by just passing the name then it would be very easy and also it is a requirement given to me so i have to do it

Comment: Which language are you using, or do you want answers for both C and C++?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan i am program in VC++ IDE VS2008

Comment: Is your program C or C++? You included both tags. It has to be one or the other. Which is it?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan C++ i removed the C tag

Comment: Why are we not allowed to use output streams? Is there anything else that we are not allowed to use? Can we use std::string?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan because my seniors have told me not to use that why we cannot use it .Yes you can use string

Comment: Before doing a WriteFile, you need to translate the contents of the structure into a certain format. See @Konrad's answer below.

Answer (score 4):

You can't just dump an arbitrary object if you want it to be human readable.

I'd suggest implementing a method that formats the contents of the object as a string. Then you can log it using any number of mechanisms.

```
class CLoggable
{
    public:
        virtual std::string GetContents() = 0;
};

struct abc : public CLoggable
{
    int a;
    std::string c;
    CSomeObject* pObj;

    virtual std::string GetContents()
    {
        std::string strBuffer;
        strBuffer += "a = ";
        strBuffer += std::to_string( static_cast< long long >( a ) );
        strBuffer += "c = ";
        strBuffer += c;
        strBuffer += "pObj = ";
        strBuffer += pObj == nullptr ? "Null object" : pObj->GetContents();
        // etc etc etc

        return strBuffer;
    }
};

// e.g.
abc obj;
logger.log( obj.GetContents() );
```

Alternatively implement the stream insertion operator and pass it directly to stdout or a filestream.

```
basic_ostream& operator<< ( abc& val );   // etc

abc obj;
std::cout << "Object contains : " << obj;
```

Comment: i want to do it using WriteFile/CreateFile API.

Comment: @hardyz009 The WriteFile/CreateFile API only knows about bytes. It doesn't understand about structure which is just four ints - or sixteen bytes sitting in memory. WriteFile doesn't have a crystal ball to say "oh - those are actually ints, I'll write the in decimal in ASCII". If you want to use WriteFile, you'll need to convert your structure to decimal in ASCII first.

Comment: @SecurityMatt so it is not possible to just pass name of the struct and expect the writefile to write the value of its members in a text file without converting the struct into a decimal

Comment: @hardyz009 no, that's not how the API works. You need to do a bit of work to generate the data that is written out to the file. The suggestions above should give you a start :-)

Comment: He's already got the CreateFile/WriteFile mechanism figured out, but he needs to figure out how to format the output into readable form.  How does your answer add any value?  It's just a class declaration with no functionality.

Comment: @CareyGregory There is no generic way of taking any number of members of any type and creating a human readable representation of them. I was showing how he could have a consistent way of generating such representations.

Comment: Of course there's no generic solution, but adding at least one example of how to format a struct member into readable form would make your answer much better since that seems to be the part he doesn't understand.

Comment: @hardyz009: The API was compiled by Microsoft long before you wrote your program. WriteFile therefore cannot know about how your structure works. C and C++ don't have fancy reflection APIs like C#, Java and PHP. A structure is just a layout of memory - it isn't an object, and none of the APIs "know" about the structures you've made.

Comment: @Konrad thanks for ur example, but here we know the members of the structure.What if we have to make it more of generic such that it works for any structwhose members are POD(Plain Old Data) type